# Geodesic of Stiefel manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic, stiefel-manifolds

Define a metric on Stiefel manifold $V_{n,p}$ as
$$\left<\Delta_1,\Delta_2\right>=\text{tr}\Delta_1^T\left(I-\frac{1}{2}YY^T\right)\Delta_2$$
$\forall \Delta_1,\Delta_2\in T_YV_{n,p}$

- how to calculate geodesic through the variation problem

$$\min\limits_{Y(t)}\int\left<\dot{Y},\dot{Y}\right>^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$
$Y(t)$ is the curve in $V_{n,p}$.

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is called the *canonical inner product*. According to [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01113.pdf), and taking $[Q]$, the equivalence class of all $n$-by-$n$ orthogonal matrices to be a point on the Stiefel manifold, we can re-write $\left<\Delta_1,\Delta_2\right>$ as:

$$
\begin{align*}
\left<\Delta_1,\Delta_2\right> &= \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} \Bigg( Q \begin{bmatrix} A_1 & -B_1^T \\ B_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \Bigg)^T  Q \begin{bmatrix} A_2 & -B_2^T \\ B_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \text{tr} A_1^T A_2 + \text{tr} B_1^T B_2
\end{align*}
$$

I follows from [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01113.pdf) that the orthogonal group geodesic is given by:
$$
Q(t) = Q(0) \text{exp}\,\,t\begin{bmatrix}A & -B^T \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
these are the curves of shortest length in the quotient space.

Minimizing the path length $L$ where
$$
L=\int\left<\dot{Y},\dot{Y}\right>^{\frac{1}{2}}dt
$$
using the calculus of variations as given in the question yields the following geodesic equation:
$$
\ddot{Y}+\dot{Y}\dot{Y}^T+Y((Y^T\dot{Y})^2+\dot{Y}^T\dot{Y}) = 0.
$$
It is reported in [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01113.pdf) that this is tedious to derive though. With appropriate substitutions, the paths of the form
$$
Y(t) = Q e^{Xt}I_{n,p}
$$
where $X=\begin{bmatrix} A & -B^T \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix}$, are found to be the closed form solutions to the **geodesic equation for the canonical metric**.

The paper also gives a computationally more reasonable algorithm to compute that.
First, authors parameterize the same geodesic by an initial position $Y(0)=Y$ and direction $\dot{Y}(0)=H$. By formulating a quadratic eigenvalue problem, they show that the geodesic is given by the following curve:
$$
Y(t) = Y M(t) + Q N(t)
$$
where $QR:=K=(I-YY^T)H$ is the QR-decomposition of $K$ and $M(t)$ and $N(t)$ are given by the matrix exponential:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}M(t)\\N(t)\end{pmatrix} = \text{exp}\, t\begin{pmatrix}A & -R^T \\ R & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I_p \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
$I_p$ is the identity. This can be computed easily by solving a $2p$-by-$2p$ skew-symmetric eigenvalue problem. *Hint: Use SVD*.

$$\\$$
$$\\$$

Side notes:

- Equivalence class encapsulates all orthogonal matrices with identical first $p$ columns.

---

I also recommend the [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01113.pdf) which derives an efficient retraction and vector transport map for the Stiefel manifold based upon Cayley transform.

[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01113.pdf) Alan Edelman, Tomas A. Arias, And Steven T. Smith, The Geometry Of Algorithms With Orthogonality Constraints, SIAM J. on Matrix Analysis and Applications, 1998